# how to find a item in a list of value and then set a boolean property

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, c#-4.0

I have a list of item in a variable which is of type (IEnumerable)

How to check for a name like Person.Doctor or Person.Engineer

```
var list = PersonList();

list contains an array like list[0] = PersonDoctor, list[1] = PersonEngineer and so on.

Now, if I want to check the PersonEngineer and further a property named "name" inside that and then set a boolean condition if that property presents with the value of "Steve", how to do that?
```

And if so then set a boolean to true.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is the type of your list. Is PersonEngineer a class or a specific instance and that is the name of the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a lot of details in your question, so I will assume a few things.

For example, I assume you have a string you want to search the list with (lets call this variable **name**) and a boolean (lets call this **bool**)

```
if (list.Any(person => person.Doctor == **name**)) 
    bool = true;
```

If this is not what you're looking for, please provide some specifics, such as a snippet of your code, so we can understand what you're asking.

Comment: Helped me. I was actually using First method on List and it said it cant convert from Person to bool, I was freaking breaking my head